# Select primary Email from multiple emails that match First or Last Name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, cursor

I've got a really interesting requirement ahead of me. I thought about using cursors but I'm not sure if I can get what I want. I have a Contact table that may contain multiple emails per record like FirstName, LastName, Email1, Email2, Email3, Email4. So the requirement is to find email that contains either the first or last names and pick that email as their primary email. Is there any elegant way to write it in SQL?

```
ContactId   FirstName     LastName     Email1            Email2             Email3
---------   ---------     --------     ---------         ------             ------
        1      Jeremy          Lin     1@yah.com         linJ@gmail.com     ty@mail.co
        2       Sarah        Woods     ii@smiles.jp      ube@mail.com       SarahW@rou.com
        3       Peter      Wilkins     wPeter@coors.au   wsarah@yah.com     null
```

Expected Result:

```
ContactId   FirstName     LastName     Email
---------   ---------     --------     ---------
        1      Jeremy          Lin     linJ@gmail.com
        2       Sarah        Woods     SarahW@rou.com       
        3       Peter      Wilkins     wPeter@coors.au
```

Comment: A cursor is just a SQL statement - it won't make any difference if you use them or not. If you've only got 3 e-mails what's wrong with using `LIKE`? It's unlikely you're going to find anything you write to get this out "elegant" :-)

Comment: Have you tried CONTAINS ?

Comment: @Ben I think the `CONTAINS` should be faster, because it can use some form of index (in this case, a full text index). Of course, this form of query is only available if the column is in a full text index. If it isn't, then only the first form is available. But using `LIKE`, will be unable to use an index, since it starts with a wildcard, so will always require a full table scan.

Comment: @MirjalalTalishinski the `like` is not in the where clause, it's in the `select`, so it doesn't affect whether a table-scan is required.

Comment: @Ben oh I see. Yes! That's truth. But I had faced with the similar problem several month ago & I tried both method. In these tests I did a trick. Yeah, it was a *stopwatch*. :D  After testing I saw that `contains` slightly faster than `like`. Note that I tried it >12.000 records.

Comment: @Ben but in this situation actually I don't know that what's the *elegant* way to solve this problem. :-))

Comment: The elegant way is to unpivot the data and store it in a normalised table @Mirjalal. You need a single LIKE and a MAX() over some scoring function. I don't know what size servers you're using but I'd be extremely surprised if you saw any difference at all over 12k records. Assuming an average row-size of 40 bytes a megabyte would take 26k rows - anything under several million rows should be completely in RAM after the first table scan, which means you're only seeing random vagaries in the system or some other process using CPU.

Comment: @MirjalalTalishinski I'm working off of a temp table and since it's not full text indexed, I can't use Contains. I had to split emails into different columns, they're semicolon separated (for which I used Cross Apply nodes method).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't call it *elegant*, but it's not complicated, and certainly doesn't require a cursor:

```
select 
    ContactId, FirstName, LastName,
    case 
        when (Email1 like '%'+FirstName+'%' or Email1 like '%'+LastName+'%') then Email1
        when (Email2 like '%'+FirstName+'%' or Email2 like '%'+LastName+'%') then Email2
        when (Email3 like '%'+FirstName+'%' or Email3 like '%'+LastName+'%') then Email3
        else Email1 -- or whatever you want to use as the default
    end as Email
from Contacts
```

The above assumes you are using case-insensitive collation. If you're not, you'll need to add some `upper()` or `lower()` calls.

Comment: I came up with similar solution. This should work. Thanx.